# change value in a object,Object

Tags: javascript

How do i change a value in a variable ?

```js
var elementorFrontendConfig = {
  "environmentMode": {
    "edit": false,
    "wpPreview": false
  },
  "is_rtl": false,
  "breakpoints": {
    "xs": 0,
    "sm": 480,
    "md": 768,
    "lg": 1025,
    "xl": 1440,
    "xxl": 1600
  },
  "version": "2.8.5",
  "urls": {
    "assets": "http:\/\/wptheme.tst\/wp-content\/plugins\/elementor\/assets\/"
  },
  "settings": {
    "page": [],
    "general": {
      "elementor_global_image_lightbox": "yes"
    },
    "editorPreferences": []
  },
  "post": {
    "id": 6007,
    "title": "Elementor #6007",
    "excerpt": ""
  },
  "user": {
    "roles": ["administrator"]
  }
};
```

This does not work

elementorFrontendConfig['settings']['general']['elementor_global_image_lightbox']= 'no';

Comment: Use something like https://beautifier.io/ to make the code readable. It'll be a lot easier to see the object structure if you do.

Comment: I ran your code, with the example assignment, and it works...

Answer (score 0):

The JS code is okay and does work. It might not be called, depending on where your `<script>` tag has been placed in the code.

Comment: Hi  

The problem is that i need to modify the value in the variable code itself. hardcoded. because another 3rd party is calling the variable.

Answer (score 0):

this works 
check the fiddle, may be there is something else wrong with your environment

```js
var elementorFrontendConfig = {"environmentMode":{"edit":false,"wpPreview":false},"is_rtl":false,"breakpoints":{"xs":0,"sm":480,"md":768,"lg":1025,"xl":1440,"xxl":1600},"version":"2.8.5","urls":{"assets":"http:\/\/wptheme.tst\/wp-content\/plugins\/elementor\/assets\/"},"settings":{"page":[],"general":{"elementor_global_image_lightbox":"yes"},"editorPreferences":[]},"post":{"id":6007,"title":"Elementor #6007","excerpt":""},"user":{"roles":["administrator"]}};

elementorFrontendConfig['settings']['general']['elementor_global_image_lightbox']= 'no';

alert(elementorFrontendConfig['settings']['general']['elementor_global_image_lightbox']);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pj704k3u/